# Can you open two files from command line and go to end?

Tags: command-line, multiple-files

On Windows I'm trying to start editing two files and check or edit the end of both files.

I didn't manage to jump to the end of both files. It only works for the first file:

`gvim -O "+norm Go" +startinsert file1.txt +$ file2.txt`

The cursor in the second file is always at the position where editing the last time. Also `+norm Go` or `+norm G$` doesn't do it for the second file.

Is it possible? Any ideas?

Comment: `:h :bufdo` and similar comands

Answer (score 1):

As Christian mentioned in the comments, I would do something like

```bash
vim -O files… +'windo $'
```

More generally, there's `argdo $`, which you might want to follow with `:rewind` to get to the first argument. (There's also `tabdo` and others.)